# Command line process not working when run from C#

Tags: c#, process, path, cmd, filepath

I'm trying to uploading a file and then using server-side processes to convert it.

This is part of a Visual Studio Web ASP.NET web application running on a ASP.NET Development server, localhost:8638

```
string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(File1.PostedFile.FileName);
Process p = new Process();
                    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Server.MapPath("/Data");
                    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "soffice --headless --invisible -convert-to pdf "+fn+".ppt";
                    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    p.Start();
                    p.WaitForExit();
```

I can manually open `cmd.exe` inside of the `Data`directory, then type this command, substituting the file name, and it'll work. However, running this code does not produce any result

What am I missing, or doing wrong?

Comment: What goes wrong when you run this code?

Comment: It silently fails to convert the file to a .pdf

Comment: `cmd.exe` doesn't take arguments like that.  You should run the process itself.

Comment: Is it running under a user account that has permissions? You could attach a debugger to the process and see what happens.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Right, I'm never reading it. I could do what Oren suggests and read the output, but that has never given me any useful information

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't just pass everything in to cmd. You need to use the /C parameter, which will open a command prompt with those commands and terminate it when it finishes running that command. Try changing your arguments to

```
StartInfo.Arguments = "/C soffice --headless --invisible -convert-to pdf "+fn+".ppt";
```

An alternate solution would be to simply run the process itself (as suggested in the comments by SLaks). Change `p.StartInfo.FileName` to the appropriate executable, edit your arguments, and you should be good to go. That should be the preferred method, as it does what you want more directly.